# CSS Border Color and Input Label Position

Tags: html, css

I hope you are good. I have a difficulty in adjusting style of the border color. Half of the border color has different than my code. It has to be completely red. Also, I want to add label "cvc" on top and beginning of the input as other labels. However, I think, I have messed up eveything. I have used necessary or unnecessary flex structure.

Thanks for taking the time .

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Space Grotesk', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

.background-image {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

#background-img {
  height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.form-div {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  outline: none;
}

input:focus {
  border-color: red;
}

form>input {
  width: 100%
}

.date-and-cvc {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
}

.date>input {
  width: 100%;
}

form>label {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.cvc {
  display: flex;
}

.cvc>label {
  align-self: flex-start;
}

button {
  color: white;
  background-color: hsl(278, 68%, 11%);
  padding: .7rem;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Space+Grotesk&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<main>
  <section class="background-image">
    <aside>
      <img id="background-img" src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300" alt="background-for-desktop">
    </aside>
  </section>
  <section class="form-wrapper">
    <div class="form-div">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="name">CARDHOLDER NAME</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
        <label for="card-number">CARD NUMBER</label>
        <input type="number" name="card-number" id="card-number" required>
        <label for="month">DATE</label>
        <div class="date-and-cvc">
          <div class="date">
            <input type="number" name="month" id="month" required>
            <input type="number" name="year" id="year">
          </div>
          <div class="cvc">
            <label for="cvc">cvc</label>
            <input type="number" name="cvc" id="cvc" maxlength="3" minlength="3" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Confirm</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<!-- <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
    Coded by <a href="#">Your Name Here</a>.
  </div> -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the type solid so that it is completely red:

```
input:focus { border: solid 2px red; }
```

For the positioning you should put the input and label each in its own container. Then you can positionize the two fields easier:

```
<div class="date-and-cvc">
     <!-- field 1 (div added here) -->
     <div class="datefield">
         <label for="month">DATE</label>
         <div class="date">
           <input type="number" name="month" id="month" required>
           <input type="number" name="year" id="year">
         </div>
     </div>
     <!-- field 2-->
     <div class="cvc">
        <label for="cvc">CVC</label>
        <input type="number" name="cvc" id="cvc" maxlength="3" minlength="3" required>
     </div>
</div>
```

That are the changed css classes:

```
/* changed to "nowrap". so fields will be in a row. added "gap". */
.date-and-cvc { display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap; justify-content: space-between; gap:10px; }

/* removed "width" of input. added "gap" */
.date { display: flex; gap: 10px; }

/* changed to "block" so input will be in next line for sure */
.cvc > label  { display:block; }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

input:focus{
outline:none
}

on focus remove the outline of input element

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of default browser style for border style, you can override it like this:

```css
input {
  /* rest of input styles */
  border-style: solid;
}
```